# What's the best react-native module for creating Accordion view?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, listview, react-native, accordion

I'm looking for the best library to implement accordion Listview for my react-native app. I know there are several libraries that are available. But still, I don't know which one is the best for accordion in terms of scaling and implementing. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used many accordions so far but the best one i'd recommend is [React Native Collapsible](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible). It has many great features and an easy to use API. The developer also provides fast response to issues and the repo is actively maintained by the community.

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this one](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible):

```
import Accordion from 'react-native-collapsible/Accordion';
<Accordion
  sections={['Section 1', 'Section 2', 'Section 3']}
  renderSectionTitle={this._renderSectionTitle}
  renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
  renderContent={this._renderContent}
/>;
```